# Why is this overdetermined system with a unique solution inconsistent?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have been racking my brain looking and trying to solve this problem all day and have not yet succeeded.

The image below shows three different lines that intersect at a single point $(x,y) = (6000,1400)$, thereby suggesting a unique solution exists.

[Three lines intersecting at a point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wguM9.png)

However, comparing the rank of the coefficient matrix with the augmented matrix results in a different rank for each (2 and 3, respectively). The coefficient matrix is:

$$ \left[
\begin{matrix}
1/200 & 1/140 \\
25 & 30 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

The augmented matrix is:

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{rr|r}
1/200 & 1/140 & 40\\
25 & 30 &192000 \\
1&0 & 6000
\end{array}
\right] $$

Finding RREF of each matrix (respectively) gives:

$$ \left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0& 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right] $$

Thereby giving a rank of 2 for the coefficient matrix and a rank of 3 for the augmented matrix, simply by counting the number of pivots in each.

Moreover, if I solve for any two equations out of the system then the result of the unknowns are the same: $(x,y) = (6000,1400)$.

How can it be that there appears to be a unique solution, but that the comparison of rank as previously described tells me that the system is inconsistent?

Comment: What are the coefficient matrix and the augmented matrix?

Comment: Just to save anyone else the trouble of checking, $(x,y)=(6000,1400)$ is indeed the unique solution to the system...

Comment: Thanks both, I have updated my question to include the coefficient and augmented matrix now, and my result of conducting RREF in order to find the rank of each. Have now also included the result of the intersection point. It just took me a little longer to add as I am new to posting.

Comment: The rref of the augmented matrix is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @daw - I see my mistake now. I conducted the RREF calculation on the augmented matrix in Python using SymPy's rref() method, which resulted in the above because the rational numbers had been converted to floats. I have now corrected for this by ensuring the rationals stay as such by using Fraction from the fractions class in Python. This has resulted in the correct answer for the augmented matrix, whereby the rank is 2 and the constants are $(x,y) = (6000,1400)$. This matches the rank of the coefficient matrix and thereby confirms that there is in fact a unique solution to the system.

Comment: Is it now correct practice for me to add what I have found to the top of my original question? Otherwise, what should I do?

Comment: yes, correct the question or write an answer yourselves.

Comment: In the augmented matrix, notice that the second row minus $4200$ times the first row equals $4$ times the third row. Therefore, the rank of the augmented matrix must be strictly smaller than $3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @daw, the RREF for the augmented matrix is incorrect. The reason is because I calculated the RREF of the augmented matrix in Python using SymPy's rref() method, which resulted in the above because the rational numbers had been converted to floats.

Correcting for this in Python, by ensuring the rationals stay as such by using Fraction from the fractions class in Python, has resulted in the correct answer for the augmented matrix. Now the rank is 2 and the constants are $(x,y)=(6000,1400)$. This matches the rank of the coefficient matrix and thereby confirms that there is in fact a unique solution to the system.

Therefore, all is right with the world. Inconsistent matrices still cannot produce unique solutions.